# ADO.Net reporting empty data type in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net, system.data.sqlite

I am trying to dynamically get the schema of one of my views in SQLite using C#. I am using this code:

```
using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (DataTable columns = connection.GetSchema("Columns"))
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in columns.Rows)
        {
            string dataType = ((string) row["DATA_TYPE"]).Trim();
            // doing irrelevant other stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Its working perfectly for all my tables and views except for one view. For some reason, the data type for the field called `SaleAmount` is coming up blank. There is nothing in the `row["DATA_TYPE"]` element.

Here is my view:

```
SELECT [Order Subtotals].Subtotal AS SaleAmount, 
              Orders.OrderID, 
           Customers.CompanyName, 
              Orders.ShippedDate
FROM Customers 
JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
JOIN [Order Subtotals] ON Orders.OrderID = [Order Subtotals].OrderID 
WHERE ([Order Subtotals].Subtotal >2500) 
AND (Orders.ShippedDate BETWEEN DATETIME('1997-01-01') And DATETIME('1997-12-31'))
```

I am using the [standard System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) libraries. Anyone have any idea why this would come up blank? Like I said, it is happening only on this one field in this one view.

**UPDATE**

I figured out how to duplicate the issue. Apparently if a view contains an aggregate function, such as `Sum`, `GetSchema` returns an empty data type. Anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System.Data.SQLite supports an SQL-based "workaround" for exactly this scenario.

Have a look here for instructions:

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/c87341d109c60a64

You're SQL should look *something* like this (sorry I'm not at a real PC to check what data type names to use, but the principle is there):

```
TYPES [DECIMAL], [INTEGER], [STRING], [DATETIME];
SELECT [Order Subtotals].Subtotal AS SaleAmount, 
        Orders.OrderID, 
        Customers.CompanyName, 
        Orders.ShippedDate
etc...
```

**UPDATE** I got to a real PC. The above will ensure GetSchema has data types for all columns.

**NOTE:** It appears, from my own tests, that you *can't* have the TYPES keyword within a VIEW definition. It can only be present in your .NET code when you execute your SELECT statement to grab data. Of course, you can use the TYPES + SELECT workaround to grab data from a VIEW definition, no problem there ;-)

Comment: This explains the problem, but if I'm understanding correctly, `[TYPES]` expects me to already know the data type, right? Problem is, i'm calling `GetSchema()` because I do not know the data type. See my dilemma?

Comment: Ah I get it. Thank you @mish256. This will work for me!